# IN MATLAB: How to save a graph created inside of a loop for each repetition?

Tags: matlab, loops, graph, save

Does anyone know how to save the graph that the loop below creates for each repetition?. I would like saving it in a pdf format.
I tried typing: `saveas(gcf,{['figure',num2str(i),'.pdf']})`
but it does not work.

This is my loop:

```
i=1;

while i<=4

    x=0:pi/100:2*pi;
    y=sin(x)+i;

    figure
    plot(x,y)

    i=i+1;

    saveas(gcf,'figure.pdf')
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the strcat() command to construct the filename:

```
I = 1;
figure
while I <= 4
    x=0:pi/100:2*pi;
    y=sin(x) + I;
    plot(x,y);
    saveas(gcf,strcat('figure',num2str(I),'.pdf'));
    I = I+1;
end
```

I have changed the code to reuse the same figure to render the plot and changed the i to capital to avoid confusion with the built in Matlab imaginary unit representation. This code saves the files in the current working directory and does not check before overwriting.

Answer (score 2):

This works like a charm:

```
for ii = 1:4
    x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
    y = sin(x)+ii;

    figure
    plot(x,y)
    saveas(gcf,['figure' num2str(ii) '.pdf'])
end
```

You problem was the use of curly brackets `{}`. They are used to create (and index) cell arrays. Also, `strcat` is not necessary. You can simply put everything inside square brackets, like I've done above. And in this case, I would say `for` is more suited than `while`.

Comment: @Roberts: What would it happen for example if my ii variable instead of numeric, it was string value?. For example, I have another case where ii stores values such as 'January', 'February', 'March', etc. How would I save my graph?. I tried: saveas(gcf,[ii '.pdf']), but it does not work.

Comment: There is a slight difference in behavior depending on the inputs see [strcat](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) and [horzcat](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html). In this example it does not matter which one you use. @Sarah even if ii were a string like the example you have mentioned it will still work.

Comment: Yes, it does work for string as well. Sorry, my mistake. Thanks